# Binding Port Number 80 for Subdomain in IIS7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

We have Windows 2008R2  dedicated server which is pointing a domain. Let us say domain name "TestDomain" under that as given in Image "Default Web Sites" having many application those can be acessed by www.TestDomain.com/appA,www.TestDomain.com/appB,etc. Now I need to create submain something like "www.franchise.TestDomain.com". I could configure the same as given in image but I have configured subdomain with Port Number 80. Will it be a problem if we have "Default Web Site" and "Franchise" running on same port number?

[image: IIS Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run all the sites you want under the same port, as long as the hostname (in your case `testdomain.com` and `franchise.testdomain.com`) varies.

So the answer is yes, you can do that without any problems.